# Applying styles to html 5 elements

Tags: css, html

Is there any drawback to using CSS on the `<section>`, `<header>`, `<article>` and `<footer>` elements? I read a while ago that these elements aren't meant for styling, but I cant find the source and I can't think of a reason not to use them.

My new web layout is using lots of these elements and right now I try to avoid giving them classes or standard CSS, but I can't really think of I reason why I shouldn't (besides reading it somewhere).

Let me show a example of what I use:

```
<body>

    <header>
        Header of the page
    </header>

    <div class="wrap">

        <div class="content-list">
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h1>Article title</h1>
                </header>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
                <footer>
                    <a href="#">Read more</a>
                </footer>
            </article>
        </div>

    </div>

    <footer>
        Footer of the page
    </footer>

</body>
```

Sometimes in the div with the content-list class there is an ul with in the li's an article same as displayed now. The header (in article) for example is always white, and the footer always contains a read more link (at least an exit link). the p's are contents.

The reason I'm asking this is because I am styling the h1 inside the header and the anchor inside the footer, but the h1 could be stripped if I just styled the header itself.

Comment: I think this has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549765/styling-html5-elements)

Comment: The only drawback is that they don't work by default in IE8 but you can easily use them by including html5shiv apart from that you can think about them as divs with a meaning.

Answer (score 1):

`<section>`, `<header>`, `<article>`, `<footer>` (as well as other HTML5 tags) have canonical meaning, but that doesn't mean you can't style them.

A `<footer>`, for example, doesn't have to implement the default visual style on every page it's on; therefore CSS comes in to play with making it styles how you want it (given your application). Just keep in mind that it's called a `<footer>` for a reason, and shouldn't contain content that should be in a `<p>` or `<article>`.

Comment: Does that mean I am using the elements in the wrong way?

Comment: @Gideon: No, you've done it [correctly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer) (an article can have a footer). I'm just just mainly saying use it when it makes sense to (while staying within the confines of html).

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks. But does that mean I can strip away some of the elements inside the header and footer elements?

Answer (score 0):

there is no drawback using css with `<section>`, `<header>`, `<article>`, `<footer>`. These are the HTML5 elements. The purpose of these elements is to make website SEO friendly.

`<section>` means main content is to be started, `<header>` means header part of the website, `<aside>` means sidebar or something like this, `<footer>` means footer of the website and `<article>` means a particular block of content or paragraph.

Comment: But does that also count the way I am using the header/footers? I'm not sure if I am doing it wrong. (did an edit on the main post)

Comment: you need to remove <article> and use <section> after header ends

Answer (score 0):

Well, the main thing to have in mind is that css cascades, and you are setting rules to tags that are parents to other elements.

No problem at all with that, you just have to remember that.

In the end it all comes down to what you are trying to achieve and the simplest way to get there.